# Decouple object tier from Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, design, architecture, .net

The situation:

- My company delivers an installed Windows Forms application to our clients.
- This client application comes bundled with an object binary (let's call it `Objects.dll`)
- `Objects.dll` contains the object properties, fields, method signatures, etc.
- `Objects.dll` also contains the Service Contracts (interfaces), used by the object to communicate to a remote web service
- The remote web service (let's call it `Service.dll`) is hosted remotely, along with `Objects.dll`. It implements the Service Contracts in `Objects.dll`

The problem:

- When the `Objects.dll` changes in any way (including the Service Contracts), an update must be sent out to the client application. Updates like these require 48+ hour notice, and a pretty hefty middle of the night maintenance window. This is painful, and it goes against our internal development credo of having low-impact deployments.

The hope:

- There exists a tool/product/service that allows some level of decoupling of the object tier from the client application. I'm envisioning some service/object discovery service for the client application to communicate with in order to get the object tier.

It's possible that a solution doesn't necessarily exist. While that would be less than ideal, I'm fully anticipating this solution.

Comment: When you say "updates like these," don't you have to change the client anyway, if the Service Contract changes?  Or is your intention to push updates to the client without ever changing any classes?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Yes. When I said "updates like these," I meant "updates that are pushed out to clients." This includes when the `Objects.dll` changes in any way, which includes Service Contracts changes.

In my "perfect world" scenario, which may not be realistic, I would like to have the application "self-aware" of the implementation of the `Objects.dll`, so it doesn't _need_ an application update, but can just update its internal implementation.

Comment: How do you update the Winforms application?

Comment: @RoberHarvey - It checks against a homegrown update web service that, upon version increase at the web service layer, downloads the updated binaries in a separate process.

Comment: And the Objects.DLL is not part of this feed?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - the `Objects.dll` is part of the feed, and I do not want it to be. We regularly update `Objects.dll`, which is difficult as pushing updates to the clients is difficult.

Comment: Is this a technical/logistical problem, or a philosophical/management one?  I'm just trying to understand what exactly the problem is.  Is it that Objects.DLL has to be installed, and its the installation that is expensive?  Are you trying to avoid the notification process? Is the fact that people leave their machines on and lock the DLL the primary issue?

Comment: (There are ways to write programs so that they will auto-update themselves from the Internet)

Comment: Technical question. The problem is that we have to push client updates because of the DLL change, and the installation is expensive. Looking for technical ideas of how to decouple the Object tier changes from the application tier, via some mechanism similar to Service Discovery (calling it Object Discovery tentatively).

Comment: The auto-update itself is solved. The fact that I have to auto-update when we make a change to the Object tier is the problem. We regularly make changes to the Object tier, and we want to minimize impact on the clients.

Comment: What sort of changes are regularly made (as opposed to the ones that are occasional)?  Do you ever change any of the business logic?  Do any of the changes require new fields on forms, or adjustments to the form validation?

Comment: Possibly signature changes on existing methods, addition/removal of properties, addition of new methods. Basically anything. More often we add/remove properties (and correspondingly change the forms that it interacts with). Less regularly we change business logic, but it's not out of the realm of possibility. Most of the business logic changes are housed at the Service tier, which is good.

Comment: Here's what I'm getting at.  If the forms don't change, then the names of the fields on the forms don't change, and no new data needs to be displayed from the updated Service Contract.  If your business logic doesn't change, then it doesn't need any new fields in the Service Contract.  So unless your forms and reports on the client are being dynamically-generated, and your business rules are soft-coded, you'll still need to deploy.

Comment: If you still think you need this, you'll have to change the way you're sending and receiving data.  If you're already sending data to the client via JSON, and you're using some library like Newtonsoft.JSON to receive the data, and you believe that you can architect your client to accept *arbitrary* data objects, then the solution could be as simple as using `dynamic` instead of DTO's.

Comment: That's a fair assessment. To get to a true ending of this, it may require more dynamically generated forms in the application, which would essentially remove the need for the Objects DLL to exist on the application side completely. I appreciate the discourse, and I'll ruminate on this. You should post that last one as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @TonyMorris does the Objects.dll need to be COM registered, or can it be XCopy deployed? Honestly though, you shouldn't be breaking your interfaces so often. I think you may have an XY problem. Maybe you should be trying to figure out how to update your server without breaking your interfaces so often. Maybe look into how interfaces and versioning used to be treated back in the COM days.

Comment: @RubberDuck - no COM registration. Fair point on breaking the interfaces often. Typically a problem due to new product owners wanting different levels of features than the original legacy product could deliver. I will look into your recommendation!

Comment: It sounds like you should be using ClickOnce for this.  If you really only changed Objects.dll, ClickOnce should see the new version of your app, but then only download the changed files.  And of course, I'm sure there are some changes you can get away with just by updating the server side. Sometimes though updates are unavoidable.  If a new feature is a new field on the screen to fill in, there's not a whole lot you can do about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need another layer

When you see problems like these, it is an indication that your solution is missing a layer of abstraction.  There ought to be *something* that has a fixed, public interface and a private implementation which isolates the caller from underlying changes.  There are three places you can put it: where you add it can depend on project concerns such as who is going to do the work and whose budget will pay for it.

### At the service end

Ideally, the folks developing the service would provide a layer of abstraction between the API and the business logic, e.g. an interface, which is generic enough to avoid frequent changes.  If a data type or parameter name changes in the underlying infrastructure, the service would isolate the caller from those changes by mapping existing interface elements onto the new structures or delegates.  A new interface should only be needed when there is significant change in functionality (in which case you'd need to revise the Windows application anyway).

### At the client end

If they are not willing to do that, you can add an [adapter layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) on the client side which would have a fixed public interface and a private implementation that deals with the raw service APIs. You'd need this adapter to be distributed in the same package that contains updates to `objects.dll`.  And ideally it would be built as part of the continuous integration build for objects.dll to ensure compatibility.

### In the protocol

If you use a RESTful protocol, the client can dynamically discover any new interface elements using the [Uniform Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172600/rest-what-exactly-is-meant-by-uniform-interface).

If you use a JSON sort of protocol, the server and client can support new interface elements via [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

If you are using WCF, you can use [lax versioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731060(v=vs.110).aspx) to alleviate the problem. Under this pattern, removal of existing interface elements will still break the solution, but you can add new elements without breaking it.

Comment: +1 for the lax WCF versioning. It really should be the default and I believe OP is using WCF, even though they didn't state it explicitly.